# Site collection relative url in XSLT search or by JavaScript

Tags: search, javascript, xslt, search-results

I have the following question:

I'm modifying the XSLT of the search, so it is represented differently etc etc .. in this occasion I also need to get a relative site collection url.

In managed property i found a property SPSiteUrl, but adding it to properties for the xslt didn't help, as i got an error "inconsistent use of schema" etc etc, so how with other words can I retrieve the site collection relative url?

Because else i cannot know the relative url anyhow ...

OR if i'm in search, and i have the direct url to an item, how can i then by javascript decide which is the part of site collection url?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For the OR part..

### How to get the SC URL from a full URL in JSOM

Sadly the only way is try and error. Here's my code to get the SC URL (I wanted to get fields of a image listitem by its full URL) 
[related SE post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110703/csom-get-listitem-by-file-url)

```
        function getFileProperties(url, fileUrl) {
            //to get the file specific client context
            //you can create the context based on a url
            //the url sadly must match the pure site's url 
            //exmpl. 
            //http://contoso/library/image.jpg does not work
            //http://contoso/library does not work
            //http://contoso does work
            //to get the pure site's url I simply add a try 
            //error query and repeat recursively until no error
            //is thrown or the url does not contain "/"
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(url); //get context
            var siteCollection = ctx.get_site(); //try get site to check if context is valid
            ctx.load(siteCollection);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    // context is valid - proceed 
                    var relUrl;
                    if (_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl !== "/") {
                        relUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + fileUrl.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl, '');  //convert to relative url
                    } else {
                        relUrl = fileUrl.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl, '');  //convert to relative url - is root sitecollection
                    }

                    var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);   //get file
                    ctx.load(file, 'ListItemAllFields');

                    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                        function () {
                            var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields();
                            var comment = listItem.get_fieldValues()._Comments;
                            var copyright = listItem.get_fieldValues().wic_System_Copyright;

                            if (comment) {
                               //use field
                            }
                            if (copyright) {
                               //use field
                            }

                            waitDialog.close();
                            if (!comment || !copyright) {
                                Utility.ShowDialog("Error");
                            }
                        },
                        function (sender, args) {
                            console.log(args.get_message()); //errorhandling
                            waitDialog.close();
                            Utility.ShowDialog("Error");
                        }
                    );
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    //context is invalid - shrink url and try again                
                    url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    if (url !== "http:/") {
                        getFileProperties(url, fileUrl); //recursive call
                    } else {
                        //else - the url is not compatible
                        waitDialog.close();
                        Utility.ShowDialog("Error");
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Here's whats essential for you

```
        function getFileProperties(url, fileUrl) {               
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(url); //get context
            var siteCollection = ctx.get_site(); //try get site to check if context is valid
            ctx.load(siteCollection);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    // context is valid - proceed                          
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    //context is invalid - shrink url and try again                
                    url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    if (url !== "http:/") {
                        getFileProperties(url, fileUrl); //recursive call
                    } else {
                        //else - the url is not compatible
                        waitDialog.close();
                        Utility.ShowDialog("Error");
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I customize XSLT for list views and forms (either as XSL referenced in the List's schema, or as an *.ascx that I deploy to CONTROLTEMPLATES) I used the following pre-defined parameter. You just declare it.. and then use it.. it's actual value is supplied magically elsewhere (in main.xsl, I think)

```
 <xsl:param name="HttpVDir"/>
```

The above param declaration goes near the top of your stylesheet (between the xsl:stylesheet tags, usually preceding any specific xsl:template tags).

Then, if you put this within the context of an xsl:template, it will output the site collection URL:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$HttpVDir" />
```

Comment: Microsoft's official list of XSLT Global Parameters can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806158(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: So, to further answer your question, I would formulate the XSLT to output a tiny javascript block that declares a single JS variable:  var siteCollectionUrl = ... which you can then reference in your other javascript logic.

Comment: In my further experimentation just now, for XSL files that are referenced in list schema documents, you can dispense with the param declaration and skip right to using the second snippet above. I think this is because XSL files start with an include reference to main.xsl

Answer (score 0):

Get it from the Global list of parameters found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff806158(v=office.14).aspx). The parameter your looking for is "RootSiteUrl" Here is how to use it. Add it to the list of Parameters in the xsl:stylesheet

add the line:

```
<xsl:param name="RootSiteUrl" />
```

Then call it with

```
$RootSiteUrl
```