# How to get web relative URL from a document URL in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

If I have a link to a document (which could be on another site than the current site), how can I extract a web relative url to the document from the url of the document? I am not sure how to do it because how would you differentiate a list name from another subsite name.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to get web relative url from a document link. Can share the requirements shortly so that people can suggest you other way around?

Comment: I want to do a hover over callout using this tutorial
http://community.obilogic.co.uk/blogs/teamblog/archive/2014/01/23/sharepoint-2013-custom-callout-with-file-preview.aspx
but the special link it requires needs a web relative url (of the document you want to preview) in the beginning.

Comment: Is there a REST api (or JSOM) that takes a URL to a document and can return metedata such as web relative url to it?

Comment: I saw this, but not sure how to use it
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246729.aspx

Comment: Have a look at my question -- this way you can get the corresponding list item for the file and all its fields http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110703/jsom-get-listitem-by-file-url

Comment: Can you post a sample of your document url? Why you need to get it from document url? Cant u you use `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly modified version of the code I created in an older question - this should help you achieve your task.

Reference: [JSOM - get listitem by file URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110703/jsom-get-listitem-by-file-url)

```
function getFileProperties(url, fileUrl) {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(url); //get context
    var siteCollection = ctx.get_site(); //try get site to check if context is valid
    ctx.load(siteCollection);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            // context is valid - proceed 
            var relUrl = fileUrl.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl, '');  //convert to relative url
            alert('webrelativeurl is -- ' + relUrl);
            /*
            var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);   //get file
            ctx.load(file, 'ListItemAllFields');

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields(); 
                    var comment = listItem.get_fieldValues()._Comments; 
                    var copyright = listItem.get_fieldValues().wic_System_Copyright;

                    $("#Description input").val(comment); //apply
                    $("#Copyright input").val(copyright);

                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    console.log(args.get_message()); //errorhandling
                }
            );   
        */             
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            //context is invalid - shrink url and try again
            if (url.indexOf("/") !== -1) {
                url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
                getFileProperties(url, fileUrl); //recursive call
            }
            //else - the url is not compatible
        }
    );
}

var imageUrl = 'http://yourfullimageurl/sites/sc/weba/webb/images/imagea.jpg'

//get image file properties
getFileProperties(imageUrl, imageUrl);
```