# How to get list item for a file from its URL in CSOM?

Tags: list, document-library, folder, file

I have a document library with files and folders. I want to obtain metadata for specific file or folder with known URL. For this purpose I need an access to list item associated with this file or folder. How to find associated list item using CSOM?

I found similar code in JSOM here:
[JSOM - get listitem by file URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110703/jsom-get-listitem-by-file-url)

I m not sure, if it will work in CSOM and how corresponding code will look. I did not find any relevant info in other answered questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten code in [JSOM - get listitem by file URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110703/jsom-get-listitem-by-file-url) to work in CSOM as following.

```
      var site = clientContext.Site;
      clientContext.Load(site);
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
      string root = site.PrimaryUri;
      url = url.Replace(root, "");
      url = site.ServerRelativeUrl + url;

      var folder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url);
      clientContext.Load(folder);
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

      ListItem item = folder.ListItemAllFields;
      clientContext.Load(item);
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This code works fine with SharePoint Online.

Comment: Use this to get specific file context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativePath), if you know relative path.